# Hibernate doesnt map the child class

Tags: java, hibernate

I Got a super class:

```
public class GlobalTranslationAbstract {
private String value;
private GlobalTranslationId globalTranslationId = new GlobalTranslationId();

public GlobalTranslationAbstract() {
}

public GlobalTranslationAbstract(String name, String value, String language) {
    setName(name);
    setValue(value);
    setLanguage(language);
}

public GlobalTranslationAbstract(String name, String value, String language, long instanceId, long productId) {
    setName(name);
    setValue(value);
    setLanguage(language);
    setInstanceId(instanceId);
    setProductId(productId);
}


public String getName() {
    return globalTranslationId.getName();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    globalTranslationId.setName(name);
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return globalTranslationId.getLanguage();
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    globalTranslationId.setLanguage(language);
}

public void setInstanceId(long instanceId){
    globalTranslationId.setInstanceId(instanceId);
}

public void  setProductId(long productId){
    globalTranslationId.setProductId(productId);
}

public long getInstanceId(){
    return globalTranslationId.getInstanceId();
}

public long getProductId(){
    return  globalTranslationId.getProductId();
}

/**
 * @deprecated Only to DB
 */
public GlobalTranslationId getGlobalTranslationId() {
    return globalTranslationId;
}

/**
 * @deprecated Only to DB
 */
public void setGlobalTranslationId(GlobalTranslationId globalTranslationId) {
    this.globalTranslationId = globalTranslationId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof GlobalTranslationAbstract))
        return false;

    GlobalTranslationAbstract that = (GlobalTranslationAbstract) o;

    if (!globalTranslationId.equals(that.globalTranslationId))
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return globalTranslationId.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Name: ").append(getName());
    sb.append("\tValue: ").append(getValue());
    sb.append("\tLanguage: ").append(getLanguage());
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

and a child class, this class is mapped in a hbm.xml file

```
public class GlobalTransformerTranslationImpl extends GlobalTranslationAbstract 
implements GlobalTransformerTranslation {
private static AcseleLogger log = AcseleLogger.getLogger(GlobalTransformerTranslationImpl.class);
private static final GlobalTransformerTranslationPersister persister = GlobalTransformerTranslationPersister.Impl.getInstance();
private String transformerID;
/**
 * @deprecated Only to DB
 */
public GlobalTransformerTranslationImpl() {
    super();
}

public String getTransformerId() {
    return transformerId;
}

public void setTransformerId(String transformerId) {
    this.transformerId = transformerId;
}


public GlobalTransformerTranslationImpl(String name, String value, String language) {
    super(name, value, language);
}

public void update() throws ApplicationException, TechnicalException {
    persister.update(this);
}

public void delete() throws ApplicationException, TechnicalException {
    persister.delete(this);
}
}
```

the hbm.xml file of child class:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.consisint.acsele.multilanguage.beans.impls.GlobalTransformerTranslationImpl" table="CDTR_TRANSFORMERTRANSLATION" >

    <composite-id name="globalTranslationId" class="com.consisint.acsele.multilanguage.beans.impls.GlobalTranslationId" unsaved-value="any">
        <key-property name="name" column="TTL_NAME"/>
        <key-property name="language" column="TTL_LANGUAGE"/>
        <key-property name="instanceId" column="INS_PK"/>
        <key-property name="productId" column="PRO_ID"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="value" column="TTL_VALUE"/>
    <property name="transformerId" column="TRF_ID"/>
</class>
```

I want to have a field "transformerId" in the child class but doesnt work... Hibernate only takes the fields in the super class and ignore the child class fields

An Exception is throw and the application dies...

I need the field in the Child class cause it's specific to that class and I dont want it in the super class and want to make a search by transformerId and I cant do it

please help thanks

The Exception:

```
Caused by: net.sf.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field not found: transformerId
at net.sf.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:74)
at net.sf.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:80)
at net.sf.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:80)
at net.sf.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:88)
at net.sf.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.getter(ReflectHelper.java:81)
at net.sf.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyType(ReflectHelper.java:86)
at net.sf.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeByReflection(SimpleValue.java:172)
... 55 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `transformerID`.

And in the setter and getter you have `setTransformerId`.

Notice the difference in cases of `ID`.

So your field name should `transformerId` and not `transformerID`.

That will solve your problem.

Comment: I was putting the same field in another hbm.xml file, that was the problem... but thanks a lot